# how do I download a internal resource or a file staring file://// using wget in php?

Tags: php, download, wget, shell-exec

I need to download `file://///3.24.116.965/dsaspdata/Dev/hotdocs/docs/12rsocz2q4.docx` and if I paste it in browser it will open up a word document. I am automating it with PHP script like this - `shell_exec("wget file://///3.24.116.965/dsaspdata/Dev/hotdocs/docs/12rsocz2q4.docx -O /tmp/batch_test/final_remu.docx");`

Obviously this doesn't work because `file://///` is not a recognized.

In which format do I have to put it in `shell_exec`?
`

Comment: Can't you just issue a file copy command instead of using `wget`?

Comment: @David you mean to say in this way http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php but I needed it to be downloaded on server filesystem.

Comment: No, I mean something like this: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php  You're trying to "download" a file, but the file is on a file system and not on a web server.  You should be able to use file system operations to copy it.

Comment: @David wow. That works. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer to hopefully help future visitors with a similar question.

Comment: @David yes, please do. I will accept it and will upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` is a web client, it's really meant for HTTP requests.  But this isn't an HTTP location, it's a file system location:

```
//3.24.116.965/dsaspdata/Dev/hotdocs/docs/12rsocz2q4.docx
```

(It may be a network-mounted file system, but that makes little different to PHP.)

Instead of trying to "download" the file, just treat it like a file system operation and [copy the file instead](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).  Something like:

```
copy("//3.24.116.965/dsaspdata/Dev/hotdocs/docs/12rsocz2q4.docx", "/tmp/batch_test/final_remu.docx")
```

(I'm *somewhat* guessing on the exact file location format of that first argument, I'm a little rusty on it.  Hopefully this works as-is, but it may need a little tweaking.)

Comment: I have encountered another issue. on Linux server this is not working - `@copy("file://///\\3.24.758.299\dsaspdata\Dev\hotdocs\docs\1981te2z6w.docx", "/me_data/tmp/42098/disclouser42098.doc")` it neither copy the file not giving any error. I tried to remove `file://///`before URL. still the result is same. Any clues pls.

Comment: This is working fine if I run on windows + xampp but doesn't work on linux server (I change destinate path accordingly). ` @copy('file:////\\3.24.758.299\dsaspdata\Dev\hotdocs\docs\1981te2z6w.docx', '/me_data/tmp/1981te2z6w.docx');`